# How to Have Multiple Case When Statements that Update the same column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a query with multiple CASE WHEN statements that updates the same single column called 'Assert_True'.  Basically I want the query to assert that the values in a.col_1 are the same in b.col_1 for all columns.  The expected results is a temptable that I can then filter down on the Assert_True column to find which pair of columns do not have the same values.  I have written the following code so far:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a.col_1 = b.col_1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Assert_True, 
    a.col_1, b.col_1,
    CASE WHEN a.col_2 = b.col_2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Assert_True, 
    a.col_2, b.col_2,
    CASE WHEN a.col_3 = b.col_3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Assert_True, 
    a.col_3, b.col_3
INSERT INTO #TempTable
FROM
    database.schema.table1 a
JOIN 
    database.schema.table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Totally unclear.   I don't think the word UPDATE is the right word here.   An example of starting data and desired results is probably the only way to make this question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one case statement will do using an OR for the multiple tests:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a.col_1 <> b.col_1 OR a.col_2 <> b.col_2 OR a.col_3 <> b.col_3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Assert_True, 
    a.col_1, b.col_1,    
    a.col_2, b.col_2,   
    a.col_3, b.col_3
INSERT INTO #TempTable
FROM
    database.schema.table1 a
JOIN 
    database.schema.table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Alternatively, for your needs:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN a.col_1 <> b.col_1 THEN 'col_1'
         WHEN a.col_2 <> b.col_2 THEN 'col_2'
         WHEN a.col_3 <> b.col_3 THEN 'col_3' 
         ELSE 'all matched' 
         END AS Assert_True, 
    a.col_1, b.col_1,    
    a.col_2, b.col_2,   
    a.col_3, b.col_3
INSERT INTO #TempTable
FROM
    database.schema.table1 a
JOIN 
    database.schema.table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use AND not OR from the way the OP explained it, "Basically I want the query to assert that the values in a.col_1 are the same in b.col_1 for all columns." Or was this supposed to be "for all rows"???

Comment: @RyanWilson You are probably correct. I have rewritten still using OR, but checking for "not equals". Added a second version which will pin-point which unmatched pair triggered the case statement.

Comment: Well written answer, plus 1 from me. Thanks for updating.

Comment: Using a single CASE will only return a single non-matching pair, even if there are several non-matching pairs.   Just a caveat, since it's not clear in the question whether this is desired or not.

Comment: @TabAlleman I think this is a good case for a UNION. Baby steps.

Comment: Thank you so much @JNevill, you understood perfectly and helped me solve this problem!